# Android Arctic fox infinite gradle build running

Tags: android-studio

Today I updated to the latest android studio version (arctic fox) and could not finish a single build today. After I start building it seems infinite, could not get a single build for hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in some dependencies (due to private maven  server was down)  were inaccessible and Gradle went into an infinite loop trying to download them